# Logging into chat: not supported for Android smartphones?

Tags: support

I can access my account on ELU on my Android smartphone just fine (Droid RAZR running Android version 2.3.5), but if I try to enter chat from ELU I get told I need to log in. So I click the login link and give my credentials and it tells me I'm creating a new account.

What gives?

Note: I've seen this behavior off and on lately in webkit browsers. Sometimes I have to get in via Firefox. After a while it usually begins to work correctly again, but on my phone so far no luck.

Comment: I managed it at the beginning of the month, from my Android smart phone.

Comment: It's not an answer, but I've successfully logged in to chat using my Nexus S running Android 2.3.6

Comment: As another (probably unhelpful) data point, I routinely log in to both the site and chat on an HTC Evo running Android 2.3.5, usually using the default browser, and I was able to get in just now with no problems from there. I occasionally have trouble connecting from my phone, but not consistently.

Comment: I love the gloating "my phone works" comments. Please, sir (or ma'am), may I have another? ^_^

Comment: ....Maybe ask on Android.SE?

Comment: @Aarthi: Doesn't happen there. ;)

Comment: @Robusto No, I meant -- instead of asking on Meta.English, ask your question on Android.SE :P

Comment: @Aarthi: I know what you meant. But 1) it's not really an Android issue, since others with Android phones aren't experiencing the problem, 2) it happens sometimes in regular browsers on laptops and desktops, 3) therefore it is pretty obviously an authentication issue for SE sites, and 4) other questions about the site's software have been asked and answered here. I ask on ELU meta because ELU is where I spend most of my SE time.

Comment: @Robusto No worries! Are you routing through an EC2 instance? Some Droid devices do that, and EC2 is disallowed to access our sites. That might be why.

Comment: @Aarthi: No EC2. Regular Verizon CDMA and CDMA/LTE and Wi-Fi. And my phone accesses ELU just fine. It's only chat that wants me to log in again, but refuses to accept my credentials from Google and thinks I'm making a new account.

Comment: Log IN TO chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log in to `english.stackexchange.com`, go to `english.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login`, and log in to chat from there without having to key in any credentials again.

Alternatively, one may log in to `stackexchange.com` first and then navigate to `stackexchange.com/users/chat-login`.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks. I still wonder why the normal transfer of authentication fails like that.